# Nuxt Fatal Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined. Nuxt Js

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

When I try run npm run dev in my nuxt project. I get an error like this.

```
Using default Tailwind CSS file from runtime/tailwind.css                                                                       nuxt:tailwindcss 21:02:57

 FATAL  Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined.                                                                           21:02:57

  at postcss8Module (node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/dist/index.js:15:10)
  at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:435:21)
  at async setup (node_modules/@nuxtjs/tailwindcss/dist/module.mjs:186:7)
  at async ModuleContainer.normalizedModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:167:5)
  at async ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:167:20)
  at async ModuleContainer.ready (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:34:7)
  at async Nuxt._init (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:342:5)
```

---

Package.json.
I just created a new nuxt project using "npm init nuxt-app myhealth"

---

```
{
  "name": "myhealth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a TS error. Using it? If not, you could ignore it.

Comment: It's not a Typescript error, it an exception at runtime. Try to update the dependency to latest version (it's compatible with nuxt 2 in theory) and remove `postcss`, the dependency is already included in the module.

Comment: Thanks i did. I just had to downgrade my node from 18 to 16

Answer (score 0):

Solve this problem with these steps:

1. Install the development dependencies again as instructed in the tailwind documentation
2. Remove '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss' and add '@nuxt/postcss8' to nuxt.config.js
3. Configure the nuxt.config.js build property by adding

```js
build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    },
},
```

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs

Answer (score 0):

I get a project from github and I had the same problem. I solved this problem adding code below to "package.json" file :

```
"resolutions": {
"@nuxt/kit": "3.0.0-rc.13"
```

}

and next I enter this below command:

```
npm add nuxt
```

and at the last part I use this command :

```
npm run dev
```

but I am not sure about you. maybe it usefull for others.
thanks.